# How to combine row with previous row based on condition in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where every row is a word or punctuation. I want to iterate through the dataframe and whenever a row contains punctuation, I want to combine it with the previous row.

For example, I want to convert:

```html
   word 
0  hello      
1  ,
2  how
3  are
4  you
5  ?
```

Into:

```html
   word 
0  hello,      
2  how
3  are
4  you?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `match` and `cumsum`

```
df.groupby((~df.word.str.match('\W')).cumsum(), as_index=False).sum()

     word
0  hello,
1     how
2     are
3    you?
```

---

#### `isin`

Also, without the `as_index=True`

```
from string import punctuation

df.groupby((~df.word.isin(list(punctuation))).cumsum()).sum()

        word
word        
1     hello,
2        how
3        are
4       you?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin` and `cumsum`:

```
# list of puctuations
punctuations = set([',','?']) 

# blocks
blocks = ~df['word'].isin(punctuations)).cumsum()

# groupby
df['word'].groupby(blocks).sum()
```

Output:

```
word
1    hello,
2       how
3       are
4      you?
Name: word, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another approach, concatenating to previous row using `.shift(-1)`:

```py
df.loc[df["word"].shift(-1).isin(list(punctuation)), "word"] = df["word"] + df["word"].shift(-1)
df = df[~df["word"].isin(list(punctuation))][["word"]]
```

df:

```
     word
0  hello,
2     how
3     are
4    you?
```